# How does cookies work, when calling cookie-setting REST services from java VM?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, authentication, cookies

I'm in the process of learning how to use HP Quality Center's REST api to query and manipulate data. Unlike REST standard, this API is not completely stateless. It uses cookies to store authentication sessions.

I've tried to implement a very simple test, using the Jersey Client library. I can successfully authenticate my user, by sending my credentials. The API reference claims that this will set a cookie, and I am good to go with further calling the REST api. However, a simple "is-authenticated" call returns a 401, Authentication failed.

I have a feeling that the cookie writing or reading is not working properly, as everything else seems to work as it should. But I haven't been able to find out if or how cookies are set and read, when no browser is involved. So How does cookies work, when calling cookie-setting REST services from java VM? Does it work at all? Where are they stored?

I am using Eclipse Kepler as my IDE, if that matters at all, and a 32-bit java 1.6 JDK and JRE.

Code, and response strings below:

**1. Logging in:**

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    Response response = client
            .target("http://[host]:[port]").path("qcbin/authentication-
             point/alm-authenticate")
            .request().post(Entity.entity("<alm-authentication>
             <user>username</user>
             <password>secret</password></alm-authentication>",
             MediaType.TEXT_XML_TYPE));

    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
InboundJaxrsResponse{ClientResponse{method=POST, 
    uri=http://[host]:[port]/qcbin/authentication-point/alm-authenticate,
    status=200, reason=OK}}
```

**API Return description:**

> One of:
>
> HTTP code 200 and sets the LWSSO cookie (LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY).
>
> HTTP code 401 for non-authenticated request. Sends header
>   WWW-Authenticate: ALMAUTH

**2. Verifying Logged in:**

```
response = client.target("http://[host]:[port]")
     .path("qcbin/rest/is-authenticated")
      .request().get();

System.out.println(response.toString());
```

**Output:**

```
InboundJaxrsResponse{ClientResponse{method=GET,     
    uri=http://[host]:[port]/rest/is-authenticated, status=401,   
    reason=Authentication failed. Browser based integrations - to login append 
    '?login-form-required=y to the url you tried to access.}}
```

**PS:** adding the `?login-form-required=y` to the URL, will bring up a log-in window when called in a browser, but not here. Appending the line to the URL actually still gives the same error message, and suggestion to append it again. Also, when called in a browser, the is-authenticated returns a 200, success, even without the login-form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log in, you're getting a cookie which is a name plus a value.

The REST server expects you to pass this in the request header with every request you make.

Look into the object which you get for `client.request()`; there should be a way to specify additional headers to send to the server. The header name must be `Cookie` and the header value must be `name=value`.

So if the server responds with a cookie called `sessionID` with the value `1234`, then you need something like:

```
client.request().header("Cookie", "sessionID=1234")
```

Related:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Comment: You were right! There was one or more cookies hidden in the response object from the log-in! I made a quick and dirty function which retrieved a collection of cookies from the response object, and then I added them to the client.request() - Builder-object for the is-authenticated-service. It actually worked on my first attempt. I'll try to clean up the code, and post a clean solution. Your answer is absolutely correct. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: So yeah, I didn't exactly follow your syntax here in my first attempt, but the general knowledge that the cookie was hidden within the response object, and not necessarily just stored in a system folder, was what I needed ;)